# How use "html-webpack-plugin" and "CommonsChunkPlugin"?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I use CommonsChunkPlugin in my project, wash it can peel public-code

```
    new Wp.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'library',
        minChunks:2,
    }),
```

but, When I use html-webpack-plugin render html, The html-result has not include public-code.

This is my webpack.config.js

```
//webpack.config.js
var Path =require('path');
var Wp =require('webpack');
var ETWP =require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var HWP = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var eSCSS = new ETWP('css/[name].css');

module.exports ={
    entry :{
        indexApp: Path.resolve(__dirname ,'./src/js/index.js'),
        aboutApp: Path.resolve(__dirname ,'./src/js/about.js'),
    },
    output :{
        path :'./lib/',
        filename :'js/[name].js',
    },
    module :{
        loaders :[
            {
                test: /\.scss$/i, 
                loader: eSCSS.extract(['css','sass']),
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins :[
        new HWP({
            filename: './about.html',
            template: './src/tpl/about.html',
            chunks:["aboutApp","library.js"],
            xhtml: true,
            inject: true,
        }),
        new HWP({
            filename: './index.html',
            template: './src/tpl/index.html',
            chunks:["indexApp"],
            xhtml: true,
            inject: true,
        }),
        new Wp.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'library',
            minChunks:2,
        }),
};
```

How can I conrfig?

Thinks.